# Transform a data frame into a table with option

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have a data frame with different variables (columns).

I want to transform this data frame into a table with a different structure to make it more readable.

For example, I have a data frame like this:

```
myData = structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "20", class = "factor"), 
Y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("20", "100"), class = "factor"), 
MethodType = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("E", "Q", "R", 
"W"), class = "factor"), MethodType2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Metric1 = c(0.970017512487058, 0.969647220975651, 
0.965873991040769, 0.966242788535318, 0.986725852301671, 
0.98696657967457, 0.98252107117733, 0.982655296614757, 0.278826941542694, 
-0.990926101696033, 0.194574672498287, 0.281916524368647, 
0.152983364411985, 1.44135982835554, 0.330270447575806, -0.369627160641594
), Metric2 = c(0.987541353383459, 0.987007518796992, 0.980984962406015, 
0.981646616541353, 0.984082706766917, 0.984481203007519, 
0.988165413533835, 0.988375939849624, -0.109331599015822, 
-0.148471161609603, 1.31331396089969, -1.34238564643737, 
2.14014350779371, -0.422879539464588, -1.25706359685425, 
1.09603324772565)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to have a table like this:

[image]

Which kind of manipulation I can use? Which tool I can use. I'm looking for something flexible that can work also with more factors.

Comment: How do you intend to use the result?

Comment: Maybe LaTeX of Excel

Comment: Look at `kableExtra` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.1.0

Comment: and https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#grouped_columns__rows section Group rows via multi-row cell in Grouped Columns / Rows